# Google Search Console API group results

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-search-console

I'm working on this project which use GSC API. Everything's working fine but I'm stuck with one kind of query : I wanna group the result by *Pages* so I can get all the *queries* (or keywords) for each page.

here's what a request looks like :

```
 public function getTopPages($sitename){
    $this->client->setAccessToken($this->getStoredToken());
    $searchRequest = new \Google_Service_Webmasters_SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest;
    //last month from today
    $searchRequest->setStartDate($this->getDateMinusMonths("-12 months")); //'YYYY-MM-DD'
    $searchRequest->setEndDate(date("Y-m-d", time()));
    $dimensions = ['page', 'query'];
    $searchRequest->setDimensions($dimensions);
    $searchRequest->setRowLimit(10);
    $searchRequest->setAggregationType('byPage');
    $siteQueries =  $this->webmaster->searchanalytics->query($sitename, $searchRequest);
    if (count($siteQueries) > 0) { 
        $siteQueries = $siteQueries->getRows();
        if ($siteQueries) {
            return $siteQueries;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the aggregationType property but it doesnt changed the result.

Here's the result

[image]

As you guys can see, there's a url coming back (url-example-1) for different keywords.

Is it possible to merge them directly from the request ? Suming all the datas (clicks, impressions, ctr...)

I know I could write a script to do it but I believe it's possible to do it natively

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried merging both array together separating by the dimentions

Comment: I ended up doing like you said because I couldnt find how to retrieve them grouped directly from the 1st query